# compiling c language program with libcurl on windows

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a simple c program on windows 10 using `gcc` from the  [libcurl](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#building-using-vcpkg) website I cloned vcpkg and then ran the `.bat` file , next I installed curl with the command  `vcpkg install curl` and got this output

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    curl[core,non-http,openssl,schannel,ssl,sspi]:x86-windows -> 7.80.0
Package curl:x86-windows is already installed
Restored 0 packages from C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 138.1 us. Use --debug to see more details.

Total elapsed time: 386.9 ms

The package curl provides CMake targets:

    find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int report()
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
           just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
           data. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.12:8000");
        const char* c = const_cast<char*>(output.c_str());
        printf ("%s", c);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, c );

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}


int main()
{       
    report();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I try to compile the code above I get the error

```
c_example_curl.c:3:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I am compiling using the command

```
gcc -lcurl file.c
```

I also tried using the command

```
gcc -lcurl -I F:\_C_\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\curl file.c
```

doesn't seem to change anything

I even tried to copy the curl header file to the working directory of the above code but I was not lucky

How do you install libcurl for windows isn't there any command equivalent to the linux one

Comment: shouldn't it be `-I` instead of `-l`? `gcc -Icurl file.c`.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Then you need to add a path to the curl installation using the `-I` option. The compiler needs to know the path where that **curl** directory containing **curl.h** is.

Comment: @tromgy just did still same result you can check the second command

Comment: Possibly both `-I curl` and `-l curl`? One for include path the other for linking?

Comment: Just to make sure, the **curl.h** file is in **F:\_C_\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\curl\curl**? The compiler will look inside the **curl** subdirectory, of whatever the include path was given -- because it's included as `<curl/culr.h>` in the code.

Comment: @tromgy I am certain that the path has curl.h i can add a screen shot if i have to but still it does not detect it

Answer (score 0):

download curl for windows [here](https://curl.se/windows/).
unpack the zip and place it anywhere on the system (i personally prefer C:\curl).
then compile your script with: `gcc file.c -I<path-to-curl> -L<path-to-curl>\lib -lcurl`
NOTE: replace `<path-to-curl>` with the curl location on the system, for example C:\curl